# How to make conformal mapping with parabola.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider area bounded by $\{\Im z = 0\cup \Im ^{2} = 2 \Re z + 1 \}$. 
How to make conformal mapping from this area to upper-half.

It looks strange. Tried to make some exponential changes but have no success.

Comment: What is this "area" you are talking about?  There are 4 unbounded regions created by your parabola and the real axis.

Comment: Make two conformal mapping from unit ball to upper-half and inter of parabola.